# display object properties using for/in loop javascript

Tags: javascript

below is a simple samlple, i wanna display the object properties using for/in loop

```
var Object = { x:1, y:2, z:3 };
for (property in Object) {
  console.log(Object.property);
};
```

it shows undefined.

but if using `console.log(Object[property]);` it works, and shows 1 2 3

why i cannot use `Object.property` to display in for/in loop?

Comment: First, you would use `Object[property]`. Second, **don't** use "Object" as the variable's name - it's the object constructor, and may or may not mess up other things...**especially** if this code is in the global scope

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has to do with notation and syntax

`Object.property` will give you undefined because you're accessing the property with the name `property`.

If you have this object:

```
var o = {
    property: "value",
    value: "foo"
};

o.property; // "value"
o["property"]; // "value" (equivalent)
o.value; // "foo"
o["value"]; // "foo" (equivalent)
o[o.property]; // "foo" no other notation possible
```

So in:

```
var Object = { x:1, y:2, z:3 };
for (property in Object) {
  console.log(Object.property);
};
```

The *value* of `property` is `"x"`, `"y"` and then `"z"`. But `Object.property` is equivalent to `Object["property"]`. Whereas `Object[property]` gives you `Object["x"]` etc.

Comment: thanks so much @Frits van Campen